# Automatically reference header files in different directories

Tags: c, unix

I am attempting to run a tool known as [crest](http://code.google.com/p/crest/) on existing applications. My first target application is Apache. The output (as shown below) indicates that some header files are not being found. These are located in other directories in the source folder. One of these being \httpd-2.2.14\srclib\apr\include. I'd rather not change the source code of apache since I will want to run this command against numerous files in Apache and then apply the same technique to several other applications.

My question is:

1) How can I make it so whenever these referenced include files are being looked for, it locates the proper directory they are located in and will use that. I can define the directories. A friend mentioned something about altering the command line input, or building environment variables?

Other thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks all.

**The command to run crest is:**
../bin/crestc ../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c -dfs

**I get the following output:**

```
[root@localhost src]# ../bin/crestc ../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c -dfs
cp libcrest/libcrest.a ../lib
cp run_crest/run_crest ../bin
cp process_cfg/process_cfg ../bin
cp tools/print_execution ../bin
cp libcrest/crest.h ../include
cp libcrest/libcrest.a ../lib
cp run_crest/run_crest ../bin
cp process_cfg/process_cfg ../bin
cp tools/print_execution ../bin
cp libcrest/crest.h ../include
gcc -D_GNUCC -E -I../bin/../include -DCIL=1 ../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c -o ./request.i
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:28:25: error: apr_strings.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:29:25: error: apr_file_io.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:30:25: error: apr_fnmatch.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:33:22: error: apr_want.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:36:23: error: ap_config.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:37:19: error: httpd.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:38:25: error: http_config.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:39:26: error: http_request.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:40:23: error: http_core.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:41:27: error: http_protocol.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:42:22: error: http_log.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:43:23: error: http_main.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:44:25: error: util_filter.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:45:26: error: util_charset.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:46:25: error: util_script.h: No such file or directory
../../httpd-2.2.14/server/request.c:48:22: error: mod_core.h: No such file or directory
BRead 0 branches.
Read 0 nodes.
Wrote 0 branch edges.
[root@localhost src]#
```

Comment: I think you should contact the crest people with a feature request, to add an `-I` flag that can be passed on to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable (use a `:` to separate multiple paths):

```
 export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/include/files:/path/to/more/include/files
```